# Story identification female mercenary who was able to grow iron nails

Tags: story-identification

It is a science fiction/fantasy novel set on some world that isn't earth. I think it is either in the future or an alternate universe. I read it in high school or college so, 10-17 years ago.

There is a female mercenary who is part of a mercenary guild. I feel like I recall she was being pursued by guild members who were trying to hunt her down. I'm not sure if there is any more to the story, but I remember that she was assigned to a mission and that she was able to grown iron nails.

Sound familiar to anyone? I want to read the book but have no idea what the title is or who it is by.

Comment: What sort of technology/time period was this story set? Do you have any idea when you read it or when it was published?

Comment: It is a science fiction/ fantasy novel set on some world that isn't earth. I think it is either in the future or an alternate universe. I feel like I recall she was being pursued by guild members who were trying to hunt her down. I read it in high school or college so, 10-17 years ago. Wow that's a long time. I don't recognize the namenposted below.

Comment: that should help people a bit. It would be a good idea to edit those details into the question so people can see them more easily.

Comment: Ray guns? Swords? Space travel? Magic?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67546/trying-to-remember-a-fantasy-novel-with-a-fighter-thief-female-couple-and-an-x

Answer (score 6):

Could you be thinking of *[Saber and Shadow](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/817640.Saber_and_Shadow)* by S M Stirling and Shirley Meier as per [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67546/trying-to-remember-a-fantasy-novel-with-a-fighter-thief-female-couple-and-an-x/67603#67603)?

[image: Book cover]

> Then, she'd been able to feed herself things like fish oil so that the growth of her claws wouldn't leech her blood of iron. The witch/healer who had given them to her had explained that it would strain her body just to have steel claws, that she would have to guard against blood-weakness by eating liver and fish oil.

It's part of a larger series as discussed [here](http://www.vaultsofhelicon.com/rocky/fifth.htm). I don't remember guilds, but it's possible. It's a warrior / thief combo. One thing you might remember is that there's a scene where they narrowly escape and wind up being doused in molten sugar, resulting in burns and a scene where they help clean each other off.

Comment: That sounds so familiar! I'm going to try that one

Comment: @Nyxecho: Let me know what you learn.

Answer (score 5):

This could possibly be Molly Millions (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molly_Millions) from William Gibson's stories. She has retractable razors in her fingers. In the book Johnny Mnemonic, she battles with several other mercenaries.