# Why would "'Barbie and Skipper Go to War' in front of an organic beachball with a Bic" sort of work as a cover for "Sabre and Shadow"?

Tags: cover-art, fifth-millenium

[This comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67546/trying-to-remember-a-fantasy-novel-with-a-fighter-thief-female-couple-and-an-x#comment395110_67603) by a user identifying as Shirley Meier about the cover of [*Saber and Shadow*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/817640.Saber_and_Shadow) by S. M. Stirling and Shirley Meier:

> Shirley Meier here. Thanks for reading the books! Sabre and Shadow is the re-written version of 'The Sharpest Edge' that Steve and I wrote in 1984. I have to agree with you all about the no-britches part, but it was better than 'Barbie and Skipper Go to War' in front of an organic beachball with a Bic... [...] – user38445
> Dec 19, 2014 at 7:50

As a response to [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67546/trying-to-remember-a-fantasy-novel-with-a-fighter-thief-female-couple-and-an-x#comment138102_67603):

> You gotta love how a warrior isn't wearing any britches. tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Stripperiffic – Michael Itzoe Sep 12, 2014 at 13:17

But how does "an organic beachball with a Bic" play into things? Assuming she means the Bic lighter, and Barbie and Skipper as in the Barbie franchise characters?

Comment: Ah, this is why my answer to that old question is suddenly getting upvotes :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a reference to the original cover art from its publication as [*The Sharpest Edge*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?47026):

[image: A tall woman with long hair, a revealing dress and a sword and a dark-haired woman in a revealing dress and knives in each hand stand on a platform with crenellations, in front of a huge golden globe with a veined surface and a red flame shooting from the top]

Note that we have a taller woman with long hair (Barbie), and a shorter, black-haired woman (Skipper) and a giant golden globe (beach ball) with a mottled or veined surface (organic) and a flame coming out of the top (Bic).  The two are both brandishing weapons (go to war) and even less appropriately attired than in the later cover.

Comment: I like your answer much better than mine. :-)

Comment: No doubt puzzling to those of us for whom "Bic" conjures up an image like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Bic_Stic_Photo.jpg) or [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Bic_razor.jpg) (same company, different products).